# How could I prevent my product list to rerender while parent component cart state updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-component, react-state-management

I have a **Main.js** component, that route to various components, including **Listing.js**.

- Main: it contains as state an array of the products added to the cart.
- List: it's a listing of the products. It contains as state all the products from database.

**My problem:** when I add a product to the cart by clicking on a button in List component, it adds the product to the cart, updating the state *cart* of **Main** component. Doing so, the **List** component rerenders, and I loose all the filters the visitor seted on the listing.

I'd like to prevent List from rerender when cart state of its parent component changes. Do you have any idea of how to do that ? I've tried with shouldComponentUpdate, but not succesfull.

**Main.js** (parent component)

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, withRouter, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {List} from "./Listing/List";

class Main extends React.Component
{
    state={
        cart:[],
    };

    removeFromCart = product => //REMOVES PRODUCT FROM CART
    {
        let cart = this.state.cart;
        cart.map(item => {
            if(item._id === product._id)
            {
                item.count--;
                return item;
            }
        });
        cart = cart.filter(item => item.count > 0);
        this.setState({cart:cart}, () => {sessionStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));});
    };

    addToCart = product => //ADD PRODUCT TO CART
    {
        let cart = this.state.cart;
        let productExists = this.state.cart.map(item => {return item._id === product._id}).includes(true);

        if(productExists)
        {
            cart = cart.map(item => {
                if(item._id === product._id)
                {
                    item.count++;
                    return item;
                }
                else
                {
                    return item;
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            product.count = 1;
            cart.push(product);
        }

        this.setState({cart: cart}, () => {sessionStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));});
    };

    componentWillMount()
    {
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('cart')) this.setState({cart:JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'))});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='main'>
                <Header cart={this.state.cart} />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/listing' component={() => <List addToCart={this.addToCart} />} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Main);
```

**List.js**, listing of product:

```js
import React from "react";
import {Product} from "./Product";
import Data from '../../Utils/Data';
import {Search} from "./Search/Search";

export class List extends React.Component
{

    state = {
        serie: '',
        products: [],
        filteredProducts: [],
    };

    addToCart = this.props.addToCart;

    obtainProducts = (request = {}) => //searches for products in database
    {
        Data.products.obtain(request).then(products => {
            this.setState({products:products, filteredProducts: products});
        });
    };

    displayProducts = () => {
        //Only products that has title
        const products = this.state.filteredProducts.filter(product => {return product.title;});

        //Returns REACT COMPONENT
        return products.map(product => {
            return <Product
                key={product._id}
                product={product}
                addToCart={this.addToCart}
            />
        });
    };

    searchHandler = (collection, types) =>
    {

        let filteredProducts = this.state.products;
        if(collection.length)
            filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => {return collection.includes(product.series);});
        if(types.length)
            filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => {return types.includes(product.type);});

        this.setState({filteredProducts: filteredProducts});
    };

    componentWillMount()
    {
        //init products collection
        this.obtainProducts();
    }

    render()
    {
        const productComponents = this.displayProducts();
        console.log('test');
        return(
            <section className='listing'>
                <Search searchHandler={this.searchHandler} />
                <div className='listing-content grid-4 has-gutter'>
                    {productComponents}
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping elements in anonymous functions in react will cause that element to be re-instantiated on every render (in some cases).

I think the issue lies with how you're using the `Route` component. Using the `children` prop might make this more intuitive.

```
<Route path='/listing'>
 <List addToCart={this.addToCart} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pass an anonymous function to `component` prop in Route, it re-renders everytime.
Instead, set your route as :

```
<Route path='/listing' render={() => <List addToCart={this.addToCart} />} />
```

Quoting from react router [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods):

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the children prop

Comment: So much time I block on this problem, you're a genius ! :D